# When using the SELECT INTO a #TEMP table,are the results logged to the transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, join, logging, transactions, sql-update

I have been able to optimize large table UPDATES with JOINS by separating the UPDATE and JOIN into two queries. I know the UPDATES are logged, but by creating a temporary table I have greatly reduced my UPDATE time by joining with the temporary table that contains only the records I am interested in updating.

However, I believe the biggest reason for the success of this strategy is because the command:  SELECT INTO #TempTable is NOT logged and treated as a BULK copy in the log file. I do not care about dirty reads as this is a Datawarehouse type of situation. Does anyone know if SELECT INTO Table or SELECT INTO #TempTable is stored in the transaction log with the data?

Comment: It is logged. otherwise ACID would break

Comment: After further consideration, I think it is irrelevant if the SELECT into is logged or not, because the actual UPDATE occurs on a table against a temporary table, which means NO blocking can occur on the temp table since it is isolated in the session, which would NOT be the case if a temp table were not created. The table being updated is logged, but because of the time savings, the chances for blocking are significantly reduced.

Comment: SELECT INTO is minimally logged. Only extent allocations. et. al. are logged, not rows.

Answer (score 3):

> I believe the biggest reason for the success of this strategy is
>   because the command: SELECT INTO #TempTable is NOT logged and treated
>   as a BULK copy in the log file.

First of all, **in SQL Server there are NO non-logged user database operations** (the only non-logged operations are the version stores and can be minimally workfiles in tempdb).

`Bulk` operations are also logged, but they can be `minimally logged` if they meet some requisites, in `simple` and `bulk logged` recovery models, and `bulk` operations are fully logged under the `full recovery model`.

In this sense, `SELECT INTO` temp table is "like BULK", it's `minimally logged`, `tempdb` recovery model is always `SIMPLE`.

In user database that is in `SIMPLE` or `BULK LOGGED` recovery model `SELECT INTO` is also minimally logged.

In [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)) you can find Minimal Logging Conditions and here: [Understanding Logging and Recovery in SQL Server by Paul S. Randal](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.02.logging.aspx) read more on logging in SQL Server.

And this is the article dedicated to logging in `tempdb`: [Understanding Logging in Tempdb](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23604.understanding-logging-in-tempdb-is-tempdb-recreated-or-rebuilt-after-sql-server-starts.aspx)